# How can I remove Shipping from a WooCommerce cart?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook, cart

I need to remove shipping and shipping calculate from a cart. Is it possible to delete with hooks?

The template is: http://flatsome.uxthemes.com/cart/

[WooCommerce Cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ljdf.png)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Add the following snippet to your *functions.php* file:

```
function disable_shipping_calc_on_cart( $show_shipping ) {
    if( is_cart() ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $show_shipping;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_ready_to_calc_shipping', 'disable_shipping_calc_on_cart', 99 );
```

Comment: Nice! But shipping disappeared in Checkout :/ I need delete shipping only on Cart page.

Comment: Thats simple, you can use `is_cart();` function for that purpose, I have updated my answer too.

Comment: Thank you very much. Working! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the below steps:

**Step 1 -** There’s actually a setting for this: disable it under `WooCommerce > Shipping`

**Step 2 -** Uncheck "**Enable the shipping calculator on the cart page**"
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I need delete not only "Calculations". Choice of shipping will remain :(

Comment: Try to disable "Enable shipping" options.

Comment: Like the label on the screenshot says, this setting will only disable shipping calculations.
The comment suggesting: Try to disable "Enable shipping" options, will disable shipping entirely.

Comment: seems to be outdated