# How to avoid that the shipping cost is added to the total amount inside the Woocommerce basket?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In my HTML layout there is no delivery information in the cart and not any calculation with delivery (it must only be mentioned and included on the checkout page). But by default Woo-commerce adds the delivery cost to the amount in the basket immediately in the TOTAL PRICE on cart page.

For example, if delivery is allowed and configured:

When the total of the product price is 1500$, it should show such on the cart page, but instead it shows 1535$ as total price, because the delivery cost is 35$. The website visitor can't understand why what the additional +35$ is about, as the product cost is 1500$...

What should be done so that on the cart page the amount of delivery is not included, but only the total price of the products in the cart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user [Sark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1587003/sark) offered a solution to a similar problem here: [How to remove Shipping from Woocommerce cart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304801/how-to-remove-shipping-from-woocommerce-cart)

Comment: Omg, big thanks! I searched, but nothing found)) My bad.

Comment: Glad it worked. I went through the same problem some months ago and solved it using Sark's solution.