# Disable tax calculation and tax information on a cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to disable tax calculation and information on the *cart* page, to have them shown only on the checkout page.

I tried to disable `woocommerce`'s 'wc_tax_enabled' like below:

```
    if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce') ) {
        if ( is_cart() ) {
            add_filter( 'wc_tax_enabled', '__return_false' );
        }
    }
});
```

The above works at a glance, but when I switch to a different delivery option or select any other available options, the tax calculation is still included in the total price on the *cart page*. See the image below:

[image]

[image]

I've also tried to edit **total-carts.php** to remove the tax information, but it produces a similar result as above.

How can I remove the tax calculation on the cart page entirely (if possible, without editing too much of the source files)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Shipping from Woocommerce cart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304801/how-to-remove-shipping-from-woocommerce-cart)

Answer (score 0):

From [an answer to Stack Overflow question *How can I remove Shipping from a WooCommerce cart?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304801/how-can-i-remove-shipping-from-a-woocommerce-cart/37305282#37305282):

> Add the following snippet to your *functions.php* file:
>
> ```
> function disable_shipping_calc_on_cart( $show_shipping ) {
>     if( is_cart() ) {
>         return false;
>     }
>     return $show_shipping; 
> } 
> add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_ready_to_calc_shipping', 'disable_shipping_calc_on_cart', 99 );
> ```

Comment: Thanks. The intention is not to remove shipping but to exclude tax calculation from the Cart Page.

Comment: Does this answer work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/37305445/9416618

Comment: It is not applicable to my question