# How can I remove shipping options on cart page and make small changes?

Tags: woocommerce, plugins, cart, shipping-method

Website: lorisperfumy.pl

I am using Flat-some theme for my woo-commerce website. I have recently purchased yith multip step check out plugin. The problem is that customer can chose shipping options on the card which is against the progress of this plugin. You can see screen shots of what I mean;

[image](https://ibb.co/gyc3czt)

o on the cart page, shipping options should be removed. “go to payment” and “coupon” and “sum price” should be removed to under the selected products. So products information area should have full width.

Could you please help me to do this ? Otherwise it won’t really make sense to use multi check out plugin.

[image](https://ibb.co/Zf9pLdy)

There is another post related to this topic  [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304801/how-can-i-remove-shipping-from-a-woocommerce-cart)

but I want product area to have full width after removing shipping area and putting buttons below.

I have tried to contact with the owner of the plugin and they wrote this;

> In order to remove the shipping section from cart page, you should customize the cart template in the theme.
>
> You should override the following template on your theme
>
> wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-totals.php
>
> This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/cart/cart-totals.php.
>
> The same for the structure. The cart page has all templates in the following section.
>
> public/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart
>
> You need to copy the template and paste it in your theme. In this way you can override the section.

The problem is I am not an technical person or someone who understand programming, woocommerce etc.

I couldn't find these files or not really sure what to do.

Could you please help me with it ? Please write like you are explaining to 5 years old kid :))

Regards

Comment: Anyone can help me with it ?